# Error saving attachments when they are embedded

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I'm saving Outlook attachments (as part of a copy).

I get an error message from the line `objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile` when the attachment is an embedded image.

The code (gratefully copied!) is:

```
Sub CopyAttachments(objSourceItem, objTargetItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
    strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
    For Each objAtt In objSourceItem.Attachments
        strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
        objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
        objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , 1, objAtt.DisplayName
        fso.DeleteFile strFile
    Next

    Set fldTemp = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

The full error message is:

[image]

I don't need embedded images, so skipping them would work too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think the path is correct and full, but I’ll check again in the debugger. Adding the attachment is fine, it’s saving it that’s the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is that an RTF message? RTF messages embed images and objects (such as Excel spreadsheets) not as files, but as OLE objects, and `Attachment.SaveAsFile` will fail for the OLE attachments. If you want to filter out attachments like that, make sure you either skip attachments with the `Attachment.Type = olOLE (6)` or only deal with the attachments of type `olByValue` or `olEmbeddeditem`.

If you still need to save OLE attachments, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - its [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` method will extract the file data from most common OLE attachments (such Word docs, PDF files, Excel spreadsheets, images, etc.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It’s not rtf, and the type is 1. So I’m still puzzled.

Comment: Do you get a valid Attachment.FileName value?

Comment: Yes, the name looks valid to me.  I'll re-check later today.  As a workaround, I've trapped the error.

Comment: Dimitry, yes the filename is valid.  Trapping the error works just fine, so unhappily I'll stock with that.

Comment: So does it always happen with the same attachment? What is the exact file name?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the file path is fully qualified, i.e. you end up with a valid string here:

```
strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
```

Second, when you call the `Attachments.Add` make sure the file exists on the disk. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

You may try to run the following code which saves an attachment on the disk:

```
Sub SaveAttachment()  
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then  
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then  
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem  
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments  

     'Prompt the user for confirmation  
     Dim strPrompt As String  
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment " & _  
     "in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the " & _  
     "same name already exists in the destination folder, " & _  
     "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."  

     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then  
       myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _  
       myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName  
     End If  
   Else  
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."  
   End If  
 End If  
End Sub
```